# Find the number of solution(s) of equation $f(x)=2^x-x^2+x+\cos x$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, contest-math, graphing-functions

### Question: Find the number of solutions of equation $f(x)=2^x-x^2+x+\cos x=0$

---

Given answer is $1$

*My Attempt*

I have checked the derivative of it. $$f'(x) = 2^x\ln2-2x+1-\sin x\\f''(x)=2^x(\ln2)^2-2-\cos x$$ but $f'(x)$ is both +ve and -ve so I could not make any conclusion. I had projected this graph in desmos and...[image]

The function is not monotonic. Now I did this. $$\begin{align} x+ \cos x &= x^2-2^x  \\ g(x) &=h(x) \end{align}$$ $g(x)= x+\cos x \implies g'(x)=1-\sin x\gt 0\; ; \forall x \in \mathbb R\implies g(x)$ is increasing

$h(x)= x^2-2^x \implies h'(x)=2x-2^x\ln2 \implies h''(x)=2-2^x(\ln2)^2$; $\;h''(x)=0 \implies $ $x= 1-2\log_2 \ln2\\ x \approx 2.0575$

for this value of $x \; ,\;$ $h'(x) \gt 0$ and $\begin{cases}x\to-\infty & h'(x)\to-\infty\\ x\to\infty & h'(x)\to-\infty
\end{cases}$  thus $h'(x)=0$ for two values of $x$ (but seems to me impossible to find which two values without graphical calculator). So finally I could not make any comment about $h(x)$ from here also. How to solve this question without any graphing calculator?

Comment: Tha command of Maple `Student:-Calculus1:-Roots(2^x - x^2 + x + cos(x), x)` returns `[-0.7538328554]`, making use of numerical methods..

Comment: The answer is clearly not 1.

Comment: @mathemagician I believe OP means the number of roots is $1$ not the root itself.

Comment: Some thoughts..We notice that for $x \in (-\infty,0]$, $f'(x)\gt0$. 

Indeed, $1-\sin x\ge0$ , $-2x\ge0$ and $2^x\ln2\gt0$.

Now for $x=-2$, we have $f(-2)=\frac14-4-2+\cos(-2)\lt0$ and for $x=0, f(0)=2$. 

Thus, from the Intermediate Value Theorem since $f$ is continuous, $\exists x_0\in(-\infty,0):f(x_0)=0$.

Now, let's assume that $\exists x_1 \neq x_0:f(x_1)=0$

Then clearly $x_1 \in(0,+\infty)$ and we need to check for $x>gt 0$ if there are roots.